# Targeting HTML page into div tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a web application in which there are 3 parts on main page.
1. Header : contain Menu BAr
2. Content : For loading of page
3. Footer

All these are div tags , Now i want that whenever i click on a link on Menu Bar my related page will open into div tag.Can you suggest me good way for doing this?

Comment: Have you even attempted to research this? Google `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iframe` along with `innerHTML` to achieve this

```
<div id="myFrame"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
onload=function(){
var element=document.getElementById("myFrame")
el.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://www.mySite.com"></iframe>"
}
</script>
```